# Combine a static plot and an animated plot in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a static plot which calculates in one step and a dynamically updating plot (animated). My codes displays it correctly but in different windows, how can I combine it in one plot window.

I am getting solutions for animating two plots simultaneously but not anything with one static and another dynamic

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import math

E50 = 5000

c = 5
phi = math.radians(30)
sig3 = 100
a = c/math.tan(phi)
# deviatoric load
qa = (sig3+a)*(2*math.sin(phi))/(1-math.sin(phi))
print(qa)

ultimateLoad = 200

def hyperbola():
    stress = []
    strain = []
    q = 0
    while q < ultimateLoad:
        stress.append(q)
        eps1 = (qa/(2*E50))   *   (q/(qa-q))
        strain.append(eps1)
        q +=10
    return strain, stress

def plotHyperbola():
    strain, stress = hyperbola()
    plt.plot(strain, stress ,'bo', linewidth=5, label='Existing Kernel' )

def data_gen():
    load = 0
    while load < ultimateLoad:
        load += 10
        # finally this yield function should give x any that needs to be plotted
        yield load/5000, load


def init():
    ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 300)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 0.1)
    del xdata[:]
    del ydata[:]
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line,

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro', lw=2)
ax.grid()
xdata, ydata = [], []


def run(data):
    # update the data
    t, y = data
    xdata.append(t)
    ydata.append(y)
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    plotHyperbola()
    if t >= xmax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, 2*xmax)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    return line,

# interval control the time in between each iteration
# repeat whether the whole process needs to be repeated
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen,  interval=1,
                              repeat=False, init_func=init)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why don;t you just add some code to the `run` function which plots the same data on every call, then it won't change.

Comment: cool it worked, thank you. I am changing it to a working code

Comment: @Arun By changing the code in your question, your question does not really make sense anymore. Consider reverting the changes and writing an answer instead (mentioning the comment that got you to the answer)